# Getting data from django to React in Real Time

Tags: python, django, reactjs, python-requests, progress-bar

I created one API which downloads artifacts from jenkins using python requests library. The API is triggered by the react front end. I want to show the download progress in the react frontend.

```
        download_folder = "location"
        bytes_read = 0
        url = 'https://jenkinsServer/job/'+ ID + '/' + Build_no + '/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip'
        response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, APIPin), stream=True, allow_redirects=True, verify = False)

        with open(download_folder, 'wb') as f:
            itrcount=1
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                itrcount=itrcount+1
                f.write(chunk)
                bytes_read += len(chunk)
                print(bytes_read)
        response.close()
```

Above is the view inside Django. I want to get the bytes_read value to the frontend react to use it for the progress bar.
In react I just used fetch

```
  var url = "DJANGO API URL FOR THE ABOVE CODE;
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then()
  .catch((error) =>{ console.log('Error');
  })
```

I found about some channels that can be used in Django to send real time data, but couldnt understand it much. I am a pretty beginner in Django and React thus please don't mind the code/ any error. I just need the download progress from the python requests to be shown in the frontend. Or if there is any other method that I can use ?

Comment: Hi Vaibhab, I googled "django download progress" and found a good post (https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/) about it. Give it read. It mentions several practices one should consider when performing these types of actions such has having a worker server. The post contains information which I consider is important, but in the last paragraph the link to a library: https://buildwithdjango.com/projects/celery-progress/

Comment: Yes.. I got that. But any pseudo code or some explanation with respect to this would be useful.